Error when using my esp8266, is it damaged?
I have a problem with my Esp8266Nodemcu.
Recently I was using it without any problem until today when I try to use it I always get the same error infinitely.
I have a problem with my Esp8266Nodemcu.

Recently I was using it without any problem until today when I try to use it I always get the same error infinitely.


load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x2b
csum 0x2b
v00042a40
~ld
Fatal exception (3): 
epc1=0x401056f1, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x40105419, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (3): 
epc1=0x401056f1, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x40105419, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (3): 
epc1=0x401056f1, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x40105419, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (3): 

I tried with a simple code thinking that the problem could be a memory problem but still the error continues.
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "RMike"; 
const char* password = "9286622K"; 
const int ledPin = D1; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi conectado");
  Serial.println("Dirección IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                  
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    
  delay(1000);                  
}

